# How to find files with specific text inside and specific extension?

Tags: unix, grep, find

In UNIX: in folders there are files with `.sas` (programs) extension and files with `.sas7bdat` (tables).
I need to find programs (and NOT tables) which contain the text "liasse". I tried by launching this command:

```
grep -rli liasse *.sas ./
```

In the result I can see a table name. What should be the command to retrieve only programs?

Answer (score 5):

This is a POSIX-compliant command that launches `grep` for many files at once:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sas' -exec grep -li liasse {} +
```

---

- [*POSIX 1003.1 - man page for `find`*](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/find/)
- [*POSIX 1003.1 - man page for `grep`*](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1P/grep/)

---

Your command `grep -rli liasse *.sas ./` doesn't work as you expected. Let's analyze what happens:

0. `*.sas` undergoes shell globbing.
1. If there is at least one object in the current directory that matches `*.sas`, all of them are placed after `liasse`.
2. If there's no such object, `grep` may get literal `*.sas` as a path to be inspected (it depends; investigate e.g. `shopt -s nullglob`, `shopt -s failglob` in `bash`) and throw warning.
3. Either way `grep` does get `./` and process it recursively in a search for `liasse` inside files. This processes all files under `./`: programs, tables, whatever.

That's why you could get a table name in your result.

---

My command `find . -type f -name '*.sas' -exec grep -li liasse {} +` runs `grep` only for files that match `*.sas` pattern. Important things:

- `-type f` chooses regular files only. This way I prevent *directory names* matching `*.sas` (if any) from being passed to `grep` (`grep` without `-r` should reject them anyway but it would be less elegant).
- Quoting the pattern prevents shell from globbing; `find` gets literal `*.sas` as an argument to the `-name` operand; it knows how to interpret patterns like this.
- `find … -exec … {} +` syntax substitutes multiple objects in place of `{}`. This way fewer (maybe just one) `grep` processes are created, compared to `find … -exec … {} \;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` command for recursively finding all files by name, then run `grep` on each file. The simplest solution is to the `-exec` option of find:

```
find . -name '*.sas' -exec grep -li liasse {} \;
```

Alternatively, you can combine `find` with `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.sas' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li liasse
```

This has slightly better performace, because it executes `grep` for a large batch of files, not for every single file.

Using the `-P` option of `xargs`, you can even run multiple grep invocations in parallel.

Comment: I tried find . -name '*.sas' -print0 | xargs -0 grep -li liasse but it returns "The -0 flag is not valid." the full respons is find: 0652-017 -print0 is not a valid option.
xargs: The -0 flag is not valid.
Usage: xargs [-ptx] [-e[EndOfFileString]] [-E EndOfFileString]
        [-i[ReplacementString]] [-I ReplacementString | -L Number |-n Number ]
       [-l[Number]] [-s Size] [Command [Argument ...]]

Comment: Nasser: Your system seems to have no support for "xargs -0". Not sure why. Just use the first variant (find -exec) instead.

Answer (score -1):

This can be achieved with

```
find . -type f -name "*.sas" -print0 | "xargs" -0 -e grep -liH -e liasse
```

If you have no `xargs` implementation with `-0` option, which is about communicating a set of paths between `find` and `xargs`, you might try

```
 find . -type f -name "*.sas" -print | "xargs" -e grep -liH -e liasse
```

Comment: This command does not solve the issue. "grep -rli liasse *.sas" take all directories "*.sas" and search recusively into them.

Comment: thanks for your help. but I need to search in subfolders as well. and grep -rli liasse *.sas. it searchs only in the curent folder, don't it ?

Comment: An answer that starts with a wrong command is not very helpful for future readers. You might want to correct it, rather than appending "updates". Or, you could delete it and create a new answer.

Comment: @vog I usually tend to to keep the history visible, but I have no problem to condense it to the final form.

Comment: by lauching this command ==> find . -name '*.sas' -exec grep liasse {} \;  I succeed to get the content (a part) of files concerned by the text "liasse" but not the file name and its path !

Comment: @Nasser  Please give feedback if the the version on the second grey line (the one without -0 option) works for you.

Comment: @Nasser You have to add your `-li` options to grep. It means"give file names" and  "ignore case". Consult `man grep` on your system.

Comment: many thanks to all for your help. this is the commad that respons perfectly to my meed.
find . -name '*.sas' -exec grep -li liasse {} \;